# jenkins - create dynamic textbox and passwords when checkbox or filed is used

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

i want to have checkbox/single select , when user checked the checkbox/use the filed in the single select , it will create dynamically few text box(5).2 of those text box should contain password/keys (so should be encrypted /not shown in jenkins parameters.

i tried with Active Choices Parameter and Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter from jenkins file and from gui

example:

i have parameters :

```
Active Choices Parameter
name: use_custom
Groovy Script:  return ["true", "false"]
Choice Type: single select

Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter
name: custom_values
```

Groovy Script:

```
myPassword = ''

if ( use_custom == "true") {

  return """

                    inputBox="<input class='setting-input' name='value' type='password' value=''>"
                    inputBox="<input class='setting-input' name='value' type='text' value=''>"


"""

 echo(text1)


                    

}
else {
 return ""
}
```

Choice Type: formatted html ,
Referenced parameters: use_custom

i created 2 dynamic html box (work only for text box , not passwords/key that **user need to enter manually (not via jenkins cred)**

example output in parameters:
custom_values: 1234,11

*it show the password in jenkins params (free text)

what is the solution to allow user to write password and text box ( 2 pass, 3 box) when another field is true (password cannot be free text)

groovy pipeline example(in case of Env:dev , create 2 textbox):

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
            description: 'Select the Env Name from the Dropdown List', 
            filterLength: 1, 
            filterable: true, 
            name: 'Env', 
            randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314439613978', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        'return[\'Could not get Env\']'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        'return["Dev","QA","Stage","Prod"]'
                ]
            ]
        ], 
        
        
        // [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
        //     choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
        //     description: 'Select the Server from the Dropdown List', 
        //     filterLength: 1, 
        //     filterable: true, 
        //     name: 'Server', 
        //     randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178619', 
        //     referencedParameters: 'Env', 
        
        [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
        choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML',
        omitValueField: true,
        description: '123',
        name: 'Server',
        randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178624',
        referencedParameters: 'Env',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        'return[\'Could not get Environment from Env Param\']'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        ''' if (Env.equals("Dev")){
                        inputBox2 = "<input name='value' class='setting-input' type='text'>"
                        inputBox = "password(name: 'KEY', description: 'Encryption key')"

                        

return[inputBox]                          
}
else {
 return ""
}
                        '''
                ]
            ]
        ],
        
        
        [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
        choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML',
        omitValueField: true,
        description: '1234',
        name: 'pass',
        //randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178624',
        referencedParameters: 'Env',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        'return[\'Could not get Environment from Env Param\']'
                ], 
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        ''' if (Env.equals("Dev")){
                        inputBox = "<input name='value' class='setting-input' type='password'>"

return[inputBox]                          
}
else {
 return ""
}
                        '''
                ]
            ]
        ]
        

        
        
    ])
])

pipeline {
  environment {
         vari = ""
  }
  agent any
  stages {
      stage ("Example") {
        steps {
         script{
          echo 'Hello'
          echo "${params.Env}"
          echo "${params.Server}"
        echo "${params.pass}"

          if (params.Server.equals("Could not get Environment from Env Param")) {
              echo "Must be the first build after Pipeline deployment.  Aborting the build"
              currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
              return
          }
          echo "Crossed param validation"
        } }
      }
  }
}
```

i tried also with mask_plugin , it mask from console output , not from parameters , any ideas ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
<label for="pwd">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" minlength="8"><br><br>
```